# Sage wordpress add customize register

Tags: plugins

I am working with customize register on sage wordpress

```
//adding setting for copyright text
add_action('customize_register', 'theme_copyright_customizer');

function theme_copyright_customizer($wp_customize) {
    //adding section in wordpress customizer   
    $wp_customize->add_section('copyright_extras_section', array(
        'title'          => 'Copyright Text Section'
    ));

    //adding setting for copyright text
    $wp_customize->add_setting('text_setting', array(
        'default'        => 'Default Text For copyright Section',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('text_setting', array(
        'label'   => 'Copyright text',
        'section' => 'copyright_extras_section',
        'type'    => 'text',
    ));
}
```

This shows me

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class xxx not found
```

Do anyone has an idea?

Comment: is your code in a namespace? What was `class xxx`? I see you removed it to hide the value, but the value is important and critical to answering the question

Comment: Also remember that 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is offtopic here so if any knowledge of Sage is necessary to answer this question then it must be closed as offtopic

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for my question

```php
    add_action('customize_register', function ($wp_customize) {
        $wp_customize->add_section('copyright_extras_section', array(
            'title'          => 'Copyright Text Section'
        ));
    
        //adding setting for copyright text
        $wp_customize->add_setting('text_setting', array(
            'default'        => 'Default Text For copyright Section',
        ));
    
        $wp_customize->add_control('text_setting', array(
            'label'   => 'Copyright text',
            'section' => 'copyright_extras_section',
            'type'    => 'text',
        ));
    });
```

Comment: This seems like your code was it a class and you second argument for the `add_action` was incorrect. Your solution will work but consider not using anonymous functions as callbacks because you can `remove_action` those. See this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#user-contributed-notes to know how to use callbacks with actions/filters inside classes or namespaces, there are many resources for working with classes and events in wordpress